# Understanding System.Data.Linq.Table<T>

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm looking at [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/10/understanding-the-datacontext.aspx):

If you scroll down a bit there's a section called **The DataContext**, where it says

*Inside DataClasses1DataContext is property called Customers*

```
public System.Data.Linq.Table<Customer> Customers
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetTable<Customer>();
    }
}
```

and then right below that:

*If you write a LINQ query that retrieves customer records from the database, then you can access that data via this property. It is of type Table, where the internal Table class becomes in this case a collection of Customer records. One would typically access this property by writing code that looks like this:*

```
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext(ConnectionString);

var query = from c in db.Customers
            select c;
```

Does this mean that at the point the property is referenced the entire Customer table is queried and returned?

if so, isn't this a bit inefficient if there's a lot of records in the table, especially if you just want to retrieve one customer?

Thanks

Comment: In your example query, that does load the entire table, but add a where clause it won't be.

Comment: Ok, I see. But if I say "Customers.Where ...  How does the where clause get passed to the ADO command at runtime?

Comment: Well that article you linked is **very** old so I'm not sure, but if it's anything like today it will use Linq to SQL.

Comment: OK. I'm trying to understand how the Linq To SQL DataContext works. Do you know of any resources for that?

Comment: No, like I said, that is so old I would avoid using it. Go with Entity Framework v6 which uses DbContext instead.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean that at the point the property is referenced the entire Customer table is queried and returned?

No - [`Table<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358844(v=vs.110).aspx) implements `IQueryable<T>` which means that queries are deferred until the collection is enumerated.

`Where`, `OrderBy`, `Select`, and other clauses are "attached" to the query and converted to SQL when the query is either enumerated or converted to a linq-to-objects query via `AsEnumerable()`.

Note that the article you reference is discussing Linq-to-SQL, but the principle is the same in Linq-to-Enitites (Entity Framework).  Queries are build up using `where`, `orderby`, `group by`, `select`, etc. and converted to SQL when the query is executed.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look at it

Comment: Is it possible to see all the code behind for Linq To Sql? I'd like to see how all this is generated.

Comment: All of the code is available at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/.  Good luck finding the code that translates the expression tree to SQL.

Comment: This looks like it: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Linq/DataContext.cs  Thanks!